# MongoDB Custom types FAIL to deserialize AFTER database copy

Tags: mongodb, deserialization

I am using a custom type in my collection, and register it on applicatin start up with:
`BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<fw9.Core.Comms.Health.HealthReport>();`

All good

However when we copy the database (via studio 3T but i dont think thats the issue) and connect to it the ‘magic’ that enabled mongo to map to my custom type is gone…

I get this issue as soon as my code attempts to deserialize a document containing the custom type

```
Unknown discriminator value ‘BsonNull’.
at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.LookupActualType(Type nominalType, BsonValue discriminator)
```

Comment: you should provide: how do you insert data (including static configuration and types definitions), how do you read data, how data in the database looks like and etc, ie you should provide a repro